# How do I manipulate the elements of a memory array in assembly?

Tags: solidity, arrays, assembly, code, smart-contract

Simple example:

Let's say I have a function that takes a fixed size array, finds the largest number in it, and returns another fixed size array in memory with the largest number as the last index:

```
function sortFixedArray(uint256[6] memory array) public pure returns 
         (uint256[6] memory sortedArray) {
    
    sortedArray = array; // duplicate parameter array in memory
    uint ceiling;
    uint last;
    uint highIndex;

    for (uint i = 0; i < 6;) {
        last = sortedArray[5];
       
        if (sortedArray[i] > 1 && sortedArray[i] > ceiling) {
            ceiling = sortedArray[i];
            highIndex = i;
        }
        unchecked { i++; }
    }
    sortedArray[5] = ceiling;
    if (highIndex < 5) {
        sortedArray[highIndex] = last;
    }
    sortedArray[5] = ceiling;
    ceiling = 0;

    return sortedArray;
}
```

As you can see, I am checking the index values of the array with a for loop and
`sortedArray[i]`. But assembly doesn't recognize `sortedArray[i]`, so how would I access each index's value?

Answer (score 0):

Since `sortedArray` is an object in memory you have to use `mload` to read the value.

In assembly a fixed-size array points at the first element of the array, so `mload(sortedArray)` will read the first element.

`sortedArray[i]` is `i` slots down in memory, where each slot is 32 bytes (0x20 in hex). So the memory position of this element is `sortedArray + 32*i`. In assembly:

```js
mload(add(sortedArray, mul(0x20, i)))
```

This is the whole function using inline assembly:

```
    function sortFixedArrayAssembly(uint256[6] memory array) public pure returns (uint256[6] memory sortedArray) {
        sortedArray = array; // duplicate parameter array in memory
        assembly {
            let last := mload(add(sortedArray, mul(0x20, 5)))
            let highIndex := 0
            let ceiling := 0

            for { let i := 0 } lt(i, 6) { i := add(i, 1) } {
                let i_elem := mload(add(sortedArray, mul(0x20, i)))
                if and(gt(i_elem, 1), gt(i_elem, ceiling)) {
                    ceiling := i_elem
                    highIndex := i
                }
            }

            mstore(add(sortedArray, mul(0x20, 5)), ceiling)
            if lt(highIndex, 5) {
                mstore(add(sortedArray, mul(0x20, highIndex)), last)
            }
        }
        return sortedArray;
    }
```

Comment: You're a wizard! This works, thank you. Learned a lot and now I can apply this to so many things.